# How to play mutliplayer on Bloons TD battles?

Tags: steam, bloons-td-battles

Hello I have Bloons TD Battles on Steam and my brother has it on Windows phone. We both have our Facebook accounts connected to our devices. How can we play together? On the Steam version, I can't see how to invite Facebook friends and on the Windows phone version, when I click invite friends nothing happens. What is wrong?